# TypeError: $scope.employeeData is undefined

Tags: angularjs

I am getting this error

> TypeError: $scope.employeeData is undefined

although functionality working as it should be.

My code:

```
$scope.$watch('[employeeData.current_manager_id, employeeData.manager_id]', function () {
    if ($scope.employeeData.manager_id && $scope.employeeData.current_manager_id == $scope.employeeData.manager_id) {
        alert('Already Manager');
        $scope.employeeData.manager_id = "";
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Watches get fired at times with null value, you need to put that check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/13617/) for you. Hope you'll find out what you were missing. The controller looks like:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.employeeData = {};

    $scope.$watch('employeeData.current_manager_id+employeeData.manager_id', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        console.log(newVal, oldVal);
        if ($scope.employeeData.manager_id && $scope.employeeData.current_manager_id ==         $scope.employeeData.manager_id) {
            alert('Already Manager');
            $scope.employeeData.manager_id = "";
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

And the html is:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="employeeData.current_manager_id"/><br/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="employeeData.manager_id"/><br/>

    {{employeeData}}

</div>
```